Пришла заявка на удаление аккаунта в телеграм
Что делать, если пришла заявка на удаление аккаунта в официальный аккаунт тг, хотя я ничего не нажимал? Доступа к симке нет, а поменять номер за это время увы не получится, что делать? (Нет, Поддержка телеграма не отвечает)

ВНИМАНИЕ. Запрос на удаление учётной записи.
xxxxx., мы получили запрос на удаление учётной записи Telegram,
которая привязана к номеру телефона +xxxxxxxx. Если Вы не хотите,
чтобы учётная запись была удалена, отмените действие, пройдя по
следующей ссылке:


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Вот тур сайта, чтоб лучше понять работу ресурса =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour //Ваш вопрос не по теме к сожалению.

А что за ссылка там? Не скам ли это? )

обычные мошенники не ведитесь на ссылки
